# How to toggle Autohotkey commands?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to toggle between two or more "Run" commands, so that the key runs a different value each time.

```
!s::

Toggle := !Toggle

Run,D:\C\DF AUDIO DEVICE\MPC DF - MIXER.bat

Run,D:\C\DF AUDIO DEVICE\MPC DF.bat

Return
```

Comment: What have you tried already? What were the results?  (Hint: Have you tried implementing an [If expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) yet?)

Comment: am afraid am a noob so the isn't much that i can do especially in the toggle case

Comment: Yeah but we're not a script writing service, so you need to do your part if you want help. Where exactly are you getting stuck? What have you tried so far and what were the results?

Comment: lol
am trying to toggle between those two run above but i dont know how just yet 
THX for ur recommendation ill try it (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm)

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty good start... you just need to add a conditional that reads the state of your toggle variable and executes one or the other

```
!s::

if (Toggle := !Toggle)
    Run,D:\C\DF AUDIO DEVICE\MPC DF - MIXER.bat
else
    Run,D:\C\DF AUDIO DEVICE\MPC DF.bat

Return
```